# Read input data from a USB keyboard to raspberry pi

Tags: c, keyboard, raspberry-pi, usb

i want to known how can i read the keys from a usb keyboard in C language on my raspberry pi? Can anybody help me please? I am using the raspbian SO for reading a encoder.But my problem now is how i can read the keys? I wil send it by serial directly for a computer..
Cheers..

Comment: Short answer: `getchar()`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your keyboard is detected by the kernel.

If you want to read read a character from the standard input you can choose one of the following functions which do so

- int fgetc(FILE *stream);
- int getc(FILE *stream);
- int getchar(void);

These functions are listed in the [manual page section 3 of getchar](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getchar).
Here is a little program that serves to provide an idea how to use one of these functions. It takes an input string from your console and prints the individual characters one per line.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])  
{
    printf("Enter some keys\n");
    char c;
    while((c = getchar()) != 13)   /* 13 is carriage ret in ascii, enter key */     
        printf("%c\n", c); 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hello, i want to know how i can read in ascii directly from the keys not from the console..